# Convert a Google Maps Link to be usable with the Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a Java Webapp based on the Google Maps Javascript 3.0 API. I'm displaying a map and a textarea. Now I want the user to be able to paste a Google Maps Link that he created on the Google Maps main page http://maps.google.com/ by clicking on the link icon.

E.g. [Link](http://maps.google.at/maps?saddr=Montpellier,%20Frankreich&daddr=Route%20de%20Palavas/D986%20to%3aBd%20Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric%20Fabr%C3%A8ges/D986%20to%3aBd%20des%20%C3%89coles%20to%3aBd%20des%20Aresquiers%20to%3aAv.%20des%20%C3%89tangs/D60%20to%3aRue%20de%20la%20Raffinerie/D129%20to%3aPromenade%20Mar%C3%A9chal%20Leclerc&hl=de&ie=UTF8&ll=43.504737,3.808823&spn=0.289857,0.713425&sll=43.421134,3.729858&sspn=0.072565,0.178356&geocode=FZFymQIdbCc7ACmxnd0lB6-2EjEC6JQodFaHrQ;FSnXmAIdwXI7AA;FQgwmAIdQOg7AA;FXZEmAIdGO46AA;FdKdlwId3uw5AA;FbQolwId8EY6AA;FdrmlgIdBFk5AA;FQwelgId8kk4AA&vpsrc=6&mra=mi&mrsp=7&sz=13&t=m&z=11)

After the user pastes this URL into the textarea I want to display "my" map according to the url parameters. Is there a Google Maps Javascript API functionality for doing so or do I have to extract and set all the parameters "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to extract the parameters manually from these URLs.  There is no published spec indicating the parameters you'll see.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I suspected ... :-(